# Ksnapshot generates grayscale EPS screenshots only

Tags: kde, screenshot

Every time I want to take an EPS screenshot with KSnapshot it is grayscaled even though the real screenshot contains colors. This only happens when I choose the EPS format in KSnapshot, not with the other formats.

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 with KDE 4.13.1.

Any ideas?

Charlie

Comment: There was an [old bug that seems to be a recurring one](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=135960). The bug resolution code means _we cannot reproduce, we look in the code and we find nothing_. It's probably related with the _postscript_ conversion filter used. I have the same. With `identify -verbose MyShot.eps` you can see that is an indexed image with   `Colorspace: sRGB` but with a palette (<256 colours) with the channel of all colour with the same value (grayscale). Later I will check on another machine. We can reopen the bug. Nowadays the procedure gives more informations.

Comment: Yes, it is apparently an old bug. I saw a post of a person describing the same problem in 2006 and actually I have this issue since a long time. The weird thing is that I can export coloured images in EPS format from Libreoffice, GIMP or even Matlab, but not from Ksnapshot or Freecad.

Comment: By the way, is it possible to know exactly the command Ksnapshot is calling at the moment of the EPS exporting?

Comment: In that [2006 bug N135960](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=135960) someone said _"it uses gs underneath"_. Bug was [re-closed in 2009](https://lists.debian.org/debian-qt-kde/2009/04/msg00018.html). 
The actual [code is here](http://lxr.kde.org/source/kde/kdegraphics/ksnapshot/kbackgroundsnapshot.cpp): it seems a generic __save__ call (line 0097). I think it's not so fast to fully track it. This is an [old code](https://github.com/xwizard/kde1/blob/master/kdegraphics-1.1.2/ksnapshot/eps.cpp), this maybe [new one](http://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdelibs-apidocs/kimgio/html/eps_8cpp_source.html).

Comment: From the ["new one" code](http://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdelibs-apidocs/kimgio/html/eps_8cpp_source.html) there is an _"eps output filter (from KSnapshot)"_ in line 243. 
`243 bool EPSHandler::write(const QImage &image)`. Maybe is because there is not  `QPrinter::ColorMode` setted. I can arrive till here.

Comment: It's a problem that occurs with `skanlite` too. I'm always more _inclined) to think it lies in the library.

Comment: Do you know any other alternative screenshot tool that allows to get coloured EPS images?

Comment: re:other tool, `gimp`. File/Create/Screenshot - File/Export as/eps.

Comment: But Gimp's EPS qualtity isn't great.